# Regression with keras leads to only "0" values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a regression problem in tf keras. The problem is that for every input, the model just predicts zero. There is no variation in that value. This is obviously not what is supposed to happen. Here is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("House_2_ALL.csv")
# data = (data-data.min())/(data.max()-data.min())
print(data.head())
print("Finished reading data\n")

data.drop("UnixTimeStamp",1)
predict = "Aggregate_Power"
print("Dropped UnixTimeStamp\n")

X = np.array(data.drop([predict],1))
Y = np.array(data[predict])
print("Created numpy Arrays\n")

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1)
print("Assigned Testing/Training Variables\n")

# Normalize Data (Into a range of 0-1)
X_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(X_train, axis=1)
X_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(X_test, axis=1)
print("Normalized")


model = keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(1)
      
  ])


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs= 200)

model.save('e-opp.h5')
```

I also save this model and then run the saved model to make the actual predictions:

```
data = pd.read_csv("House_2_ALL.csv")
# data = (data-data.min())/(data.max()-data.min())
print(data.head())
print("Finished reading data\n")

data.drop("UnixTimeStamp",1)
predict = "Aggregate_Power"
print("Dropped UnixTimeStamp\n")

X = np.array(data.drop([predict],1))
Y = np.array(data[predict])
print("Created numpy Arrays\n")

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.1)
print("Assigned Testing/Training Variables\n")

new_model = load_model("e-opp.h5")

prediction = new_model.predict([X_test])
counter = 0
y_true = []
y_pred = []
x_list = []
counter = 0
n = 1500
for i in range(len(Y_test)):
    counter +=1
    x_list.append(counter)
    a = np.argmax(prediction[i])
    y_pred.append(a)
    b = Y_test[i]
    y_true.append(b)
    if a == b:
        counter+=1
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"{i}. ", "Prediction: ", np.argmax(prediction[i]), " Actual Value: ", Y_test[i],"\n")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + f"{i}. ", "Prediction: ", np.argmax(prediction[i]), " Actual Value: ", Y_test[i],"\n")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Could there be an issue in the loading of the model?

Comment: Before of save the model make a prediction.. it returns 0? or only after load the model?

Comment: @Freddy Daniel after loading the model

Comment: What happens during the training?

Comment: Try loading your model of this way: `trained_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model.5')`

Comment: @dus ! Sigmoid is preferred activation function for Binary classficiation. Add activation function = sigmoid in last layers, Add one more hidden layer with 32 neurons to see the difference.